# undefined http host and request uri

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

i have my website on the server and i have added a new web page and when i try to include the config file in my code i am getting this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "notFound"
}
],
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}
Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in /home/eblatech/insights.ebla-tech.com/admin/includes/config.php on line 7
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /home/eblatech/insights.ebla-tech.com/admin/includes/config.php on line 7

this is the config file:

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(2*3600,"/");
session_start();
$APP_ROOT = "../admin/";
$FILES_ROOT = "/insights-dashboard/admin/files/";
$MODEL_ROOT = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../');
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
define("SESSION", "insightEbla");
define("DEFAULT_LANGUAGE", "en");
// var_dump($_SESSION);
// exit;
if (!isset($_SESSION[SESSION]['lang']) || empty($_SESSION[SESSION]['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION[SESSION]['lang'] = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
};
$current_lang = $_SESSION[SESSION]['lang'];
if ($_SESSION[SESSION]['lang'] == 'ar') {
    require_once "lang/ar.php";
} else {
    require_once "lang/en.php";
}
require_once "page_names.php";
require_once "enum.php";
require_once  $MODEL_ROOT . '/model/db_endpoint.php';
require_once "authentication.php";
require_once "functions.php";
require_once "authorization.php";
require_once "pages_includes.php";
```

and this is the main code i am trying to make it work:

```
<?php
include_once '../../google-api-php-client-2.4.0/vendor/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located
include_once './MyBusiness.php';
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
include_once "../../includes/config.php";
$client = new Google_Client();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost")) {
    $client->setAuthConfig('../client_secret_for_Google_my_bussniss.json');
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('../Google-My-Business-tokens.json'));

}else{
    $client->setAuthConfig('/home/eblatech/insights-secrets/client_secret_for_Google_my_bussniss.json');
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('/home/eblatech/insights-secrets/Google-My-Business-tokens.json'));
}

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage');
$refreshToken = $json->refreshToken;
$_SESSION['access_token']=$json->access_token;

if (isset($refreshToken) && $refreshToken)  {
    $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    $mybusinessService = new Google_Service_Mybusiness($client);
    $posts = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations_localPosts;
    $x=$posts->get("BlackSwanLimos");
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($x); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in the browser, or are you testing this on the CLI?

Comment: from the browser

Comment: You are going to have to inspect `$_SERVER`. It _might_ be possible that those two keys are getting lost from your server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) before PHP gets access to it. Regardless, this isn't a Google API problem, just a missing array key which might be server-related.

Comment: you are including a file: include_once "../../includes/config.php"; does it exist in your server ? is the path correct? you are going back 2 folders and then inside a folder named "include", it expects to see the file config.php.

Answer (score 0):

you will get this error only when you run the php file from the CLI. if you calling file on scheduled tasks please check your  file execute method. (e.g. run script or fetch url)

Test code:

```
<?php
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo  $actual_link;
```

1. Test result on Apache (successful)

[image: test 1]

2. Test result with CLI serve folder (successful)

[image]

3. Test result with CLI running test.php (completed with error)
   [image]